# Finding out type of a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

Lets say I have a generic class:

```
class Foo {
//    protected Type t;

//    public void SetT(string strval) {
//        ((Foo<t>)this).Set(strval);
//    }
}

class Foo<T> : Foo {
    private T val;

    public void Set(string strval) {
        if (this is Foo<float>) {
            this.val = float.Parse(strval);
        } else if (this is Foo<int>) {
            this.val = int.Parse(strval);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I create an object and put it in an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
a.Append(new Foo<float>);
```

And then I forget the type of Foo<>. Now, how do I Set? I tried the obvious candidates:

```
(Foo)a[0].Set("5.0");
(Foo<a[0].GetType()>)a[0].Set("5.0");
```

but those failed.

Is there a way I can call that Set method without explicitly knowing the type of Foo<>?

If not, can I somehow save type of Foo into Foo.t, and then uncomment and use Foo.SetT?

Ah, generics. Very nice tool if you know how to use them :-)

Regards,
dijxtra

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use generics here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's absolutely no reason to be using generics here. Generics are intended to be used when the type of operations you will be performing are *generic*. In other words, they are *independent of the type(s) on which they are performed.* You are doing the opposite: the operation will be *different* depending on the types.

Given that, you should remove the generic parameter, make `Set()` and `Foo` `abstract`, and derive appropriate classes to handle the different types:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract void Set(string value);
}

class FooDouble : Foo
{
    double val;
    public override void Set(string value)
    {
        this.val = double.Parse(value);
    }
}

// Etc.
```

Then, you should be storing your `Foo`s in a `List<T>`:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
fooList.Add(new FooDouble());
```

Later, you can say this:

```
fooList[0].Set("5.0");
```

And it will just work! No need to remember!

Comment: Lots of great answers, but this one showed me most clearly what I was doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

One way is to make your generic `Foo` class implement an interface:

```
interface IFoo {
    void Set(string strval);
}

class Foo<T> : IFoo {
    private T val;

    public void Set(string strval) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you can cast to `IFoo` and call `Set()`:

```
((IFoo)a[0]).Set("5.0");
```

Comment: This is the valid answer.
But, if yo are interested on how to get the type of a generic type, you can do this:

    typeof(Foo<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(float));

Comment: @David He still needs switching logic inside `Set()`, which pretty much defeats the purpose of using generics here.

Comment: The question wasn't about whether or not generics is appropriate for this particular case, but about making use of a generic class when you don't know its type.

Comment: @DavidBrown: That's true, but it's generally encouraged that you answer the original question (if possible), but still make suggestions if you see the OP is doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You want to override the implementation of `Set` in the derived classes.

```
class Foo { 
    public virtual void Set(string val);
}
class Foo<T> : Foo { 
    public override void Set(string val);
}
```

Comment: +1, though the OP should also be using a `List<Foo>`, not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Jimmy Overriding makes sense, but the generics don't. The `Set()` method will still need to switch on the type of `T`, which (largely) defeats the purpose of having generics at all.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Jimmy pointed out for your base class, you could use a generic collection instead of an `ArrayList` and make use of a type converter:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Set(string value);
}

public class Foo<T> : IFoo
{
    private T val;

    public void Set(string value)
    {
        var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

        if(typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
        {
            val = (T)typeConverter.ConvertFromString(value);
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

The above will work with either your ArrayList:

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
a.Append(new Foo<float>());

((IFoo)a[0]).Set("123.4");
```

Or with a typed collection:

```
List<IFoo> list = new List<IFoo>();
list.Add(new Foo<float>());

list[0].Set("123.4");
```

As an added bonus, you don't need to have an `if` statement in your `Set` method and try to account for all possible types.

Comment: This is pretty sweet solution. It's actually generic!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the type parameter that was used in you generic, use the GetGenericArguments method.

```
class Foo<T> {
    int input_as_int;
    float input_as_float;


    public void Set(string strval) {
        if (this.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First() == typeof(float)) {
            this.input_as_float = float.Parse(strval);
        } else if (this.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First() == typeof(int)) {
            this.input_as_int = int.Parse(strval);
        }
        // Else .. throw an exception? return default value? return 0? what makes sense to your application
    }
```

or alternately if you could by pass the Interface entirely and pass the input string in the constructor.

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo (string input)
    {
        var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

        if (typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
        {
            Value = (T)typeConverter.ConvertFromString(input);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }

    public T Value { get; set;
    }
}
```

then you can just use it like so.

```
var test = new List<int> Foo ("3");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Foo {
}

class Foo<T> : Foo {
    private T val;

    public void Set(string strval) {
        var _type = typeof(T);
        val = (T)(_type.InvokeMember("Parse", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, new Object[] { strval }));
    }
    override public string ToString(){
        return String.Format("{0}", val);
    } 
}
class Sample {
    static void Main(string[] args){
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        a.Add(new Foo<float>());
        a.Add(new Foo<int>());

        dynamic ax = a[0];
        ax.Set("5.5");
        ax = a[1];
        ax.Set("55");
//EDIT
//But I may have to set the float value to Foo <int> If you forgot
//        ((Foo<float>)a[0]).Set("5.5");
//        ((Foo<int>)a[1]).Set("55");
        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", a[0], a[1]);
    }
}
```